# Help identify this derailleur hanger

Tags: repair, derailleur-hanger

I need to buy a new derailleur but I can't find the same derailleur hanger, I checked all of the websites but I still can't find it. I don't want to buy it from a bike shop yet because it's more expensive than buying it online, it costs RM40-100 (depending on what hanger it is) on my bike shop and buying it online cost RM5, that's why I want to buy it online.

Here is the picture of the hanger and thank you.
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://derailleurhanger.com/shop/ check here!

Comment: The key info needed is the make and model of your bike. Can you add that to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're after a replacement, derailleurhanger.com sells aftermarket replacements for many different bikes. The derailleur hanger in your photo looks like [hanger 64](https://derailleurhanger.com/product/derailleur-hanger-64/) in their range.

Wheels Manufacturing are another company supplying aftermarket hangers and they also produce a [hanger 64](https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/all-derailleur-hangers/derailleur-hanger-64.html).

I've also found an option closer to your budget on Aliexpress. Hanger 49 on [this listing](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-MTB-Mountain-Bike-Bicycle-Rear-Derailleur-Hanger-Frame-Dropout-Drop-out-Gear-Mech-Hangers/32776111343.html) looks like a match as well. Unfortunately I have no experience with this vendor, so I can't tell you if the quality will be to the standard of the others that I linked.

Comment: Hopefully 64 is the magic number!

Comment: @Swifty - I thought 42 was the answer to everything!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that the price of a decent hanger from major US sellers is way above the budget you are looking at. The $30 cost before shipping is higher than the up to 100RM you don’t want to pay locally ($30 seems to be about 120 RM).

I understand that money is important, but in this case some of the money you would pay a local shop goes towards the expertise they hold and the risk that they take. Let’s say you order internationally and pay money + shipping + tax and find out it doesn’t quite fit the bike, you’ll be losing money. If the shop takes the risk of ordering the part, your money is safe until they fit the correct part.

I think that the 5RM ($1.22) price point you are looking for will be alien to most US,euro,aussie etc users here, but maybe someone cleverer than me will know how to search more locally to Malaysia and can be more helpful.

CSU’s answer seems to identify the hanger, but if you can’t find one matching on local websites for the price you want to pay then my answer is sorry you’ll have to accept and pay for, the expertise of your local shop.

Comment: This seems like an extended comment on CSU’s andwer

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus aye maybe right. I’ve edited down a bit to be more separate.