# What hanger is compatible with Shimano Claris RD R200?

Tags: derailleur-hanger

Trying to find a rear derailleur hanger that works with the Shimano Claris R2000 8 speed, on my REI Co-op bike. Have done  lots of searching on Shimano's site and Amazon and Google. What am I missing? I think Shimano doesn't have branded/proprietary  hangers; if that's the case, how can I find another brand of hanger that I know will fit?

If helpful, the bike specs here: https://www.rei.com/product/106309/co-op-cycles-ard-11w-womens-bike.

Comment: See this question for an example of a solved query: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/60163/help-identify-this-derailleur-hanger/60176#60176

Comment: The mounting bolt on derailleurs is standardized to [M10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_metric_screw_thread) , so all derailleurs will mount on all hangers (or frames). As answers say, it's the frame end of the hanger that is different on different frames

Answer (score 7):

Derailleur hangers are specific to the frame, not the derailleur. Do you not have a hanger at all or is it just broken? If it's broken, then it's usually not too hard to find a matching aftermarket one from [Wheels Manufacturing](https://wheelsmfg.com/) or [derailleurhanger.com](https://derailleurhanger.com/). Have you contacted the manufacturer to see if they sell it separately?

Answer (score 4):

The hanger is part of the frame, not part of the groupset/derailleur.

If its a REI house brand, they will be able to supply exactly the right hanger.

Depending on price, you might consider a second as a spare for your on-bike toolkit.  Remember they're "mechanical fuses" to protect your bike frame and to some extent the rear mech from further damage.